# Division algorithm when $b < 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

In the book *Elementary number theory* by Jones a standard proof for division algorithm is provided. Just for context here is Theorem 1.1:

> If $a$ and $b$ are integers with $b > 0$, then there is a unique pair of integers $q$ and $r$ such that $$a=qb+r$$ and $$0\le r < b$$

After proving the algorithm this is what happens:

> We can now deal with the case $b < 0$: since $-b > 0$, Theorem 1.1 implies that there exist integers $q'$ and $r$ such that $a = q'(-b) + r$ and $0 \le r < -b$, so putting $q = -q'$ we again have $a=qb + r$.

I want to know if I understand this correctly. Since $b$ is negative he puts the negative sign so he can get a positive number and with it enable him to write it in the form of Theorem 1.1. Now I don't understand negating the $q'$. Why does the author do all the other stuff with $q$ when he already has it written in the desired form?

Comment: $$ q'(-b)=-q'b=qb $$

Comment: What is the reason for this? Just so $q'(-b)$ could be written as $qb$?

Comment: Because we set $q=-q'$.

Comment: I understand, but why was it set like that?

Comment: Because we want to have the same form as when $b>0$.

Comment: The "reason" is that we wish to convert $\,q'(-b)+r\,$ to the form $\,q\,b + r,\,$ which is the form claimed by the Division Algorithm when dividing by $\,b.\ $ But that's easy using $\,q'(-b) = (-q')b,\ $ so we can choose $\, q = -q'\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

If $b<0$, apply the division theorem to $a$ and $-b$. This gives
$$a = q'(-b) + r$$
where $0\leq r<-b$. Then write
$$a = (-q')b + r$$
and you have the decomposition intended (with $q=-q'$).

The general form of the integer division theorem is that for all integers $a,b$ with $b\ne 0$, there are uniquely determined integers $q,r$ such that
$$a  = qb+r \wedge 0\leq r<|b|.$$

Comment: So in the first step we negate the $b$ because we need a positive number to even do the division algorithm. Then just rearrange it so $b$ does not stay negative and to get the original form. Is that right?

Comment: We want the remainder to be nonnegative.

Comment: The remainder is nonnegative all the time, what do you mean by that?

Comment: See my added comment.

Comment: I understand that. I just wanted to know if my first comment was correct. 'negate the $b$ because we need a positive number to even do the division algorithm.'

Comment: If $b<0$, the replacement $b := -b$ is used in the proof of existence showing that $q,r$ exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Comment: @MichaelMunta The point is to *reduce* division by negative divisors to division by positive divisors, using said sign twiddling.  We don't "need" to do it that way, but it is a common comvenient way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Because $a$ and $b$ are fixed and we need to determine quotient and remainder and because for $b<0$, he has changed $b$ to $-b$, we need to find quotient for this case i.e $q=-q'$.